# rails select2 adds empty "" to array

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, jquery-select2

which messes up my validation, because if user doesn't select the array is still made with "" inside.   my validation is recipients: [].   I can take out the "", but the array is still there and so the validation passes.

form

```
<%= simple_form_for(mail, remote: true, format: :js) do |f| %>

      <%= f.input :recipients, as: :select, input_html:  { multiple: true, id: "recipients", include_hidden: false } %>
```

script

```
function templateDropDownFormat (item) {
    return item.text;
  }

  function templateSelectionFormat (item) {
    return item.text;
  }

  $("#recipients").select2({
    placeholder: "To:",
    multiple: true,
    ajax: {
      url: "/mails",
      dataType: 'json',
      delay: 250,
      data: function (params) {
        return {
          q: params.term, // search term
          page: params.page
        };
      },

      processResults: function (data, params) { 
        // parse the results into the format expected by Select2
        // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
        // alter the remote JSON data, except to indicate that infinite
        // scrolling can be used
        params.page = params.page || 1;
        return {
          results: $.map(data, function(cnut) {
              return { 
                text: cnut.name + ", " + cnut.city + ", " + cnut.country + " (" + cnut.account_type + ")",
                id: cnut.account_type + "," + cnut.id,
              };  
          }),
          pagination: {
            more: (params.page * 30) < data.total_count
          }
        };
      },
      cache: true
    },
    escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }, // let our custom formatter work
    minimumInputLength: 1,
    templateResult: templateDropDownFormat, // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
    templateSelection: templateSelectionFormat// omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
  });
```